# Device detect with xcode ! {iPhone SDK}

Tags: iphone, sdk

is there any way to detect device with xcode ? i mean when my app runs on the iphone 3g , show an alert an says this feature works only 3gs 
thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't detect by device, but by feature.

For example, if you require the compass, add the `magnetometer` value into the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` array of the `Info.plist` (and the AppStore will filter the app for iPhone 3G.)

See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html for detail.

Comment: Thank you Kenny  you always help me, but , for example i have button and the button doing something that works only on 3GS and when user on the 3G chose the button ,  UIAlertView pop up and show the message